# How to find out which host Hadoop job is submitted from?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there some place in hadoop UI or CLI to get which host some job is submitted from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration of your job should contain `mapreduce.job.submithostname`. The job configuration should be visible in the resource managers web UI under Job --> Configuration.